# FireBase Analytics with Unity causes Linker error

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have a Unity project for iOS platform. After integrating *firebaseAnalytics.unitypackage*, got following linker error in XCode:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRApp", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in 
libApp.a(app_ios_3c1f2f5540e3edfbae8c7bf918ae5900.o)
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIROptions", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in 
libApp.a(app_ios_3c1f2f5540e3edfbae8c7bf918ae5900.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
```

I am using Unity 5.4.0 on XCode 8.3.2.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: encoutered the same issue today. Did you managed to find a solution ?